# How to print very double value without scientific expression

Tags: java

In my code I'm calculating a double value and sending it in API response. The value that comes after calculation is 0.0005 but I'm getting 5.0E-4 that also means 0.0005. I don't want the value to come as scientefic expression. In the API response class, the variable is of Double type and I want to send 0.0005 in it. Can somebody help me in formatting this double value? I'm using Java.

I have used DecimalFormat class but that doesn't work.

Comment: Q: Have you tried [String.format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), e.g. `System.out.println(String.format("%0.5f", d))`?  See also https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-format-a-double-in-java/ or https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

Comment: Please show the code which converts this value to a string. It sounds as though you may be converting an object to a JSON response. We need to know exactly what you're doing to be able to help you.

Comment: To set the value in the response, you have nothing special to do since it's of type `Double`. It's when you want to print it or converting it to a string that you need to be format it. In other words, 0.0005 and 5.0E-4 are the same value formatted differently.

Comment: *"I have used DecimalFormat class but that doesn't work."* - Show us the code.  I'm sure that DecimalFormat can be used for this ... provided you use it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you have tried using **DecimalFormat** and it didn't work, it's possible that you might not have used the correct pattern or made some mistake while applying the formatting.

Try this way:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double value = 0.0005;

        // Create a DecimalFormat object with the desired pattern
        DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.0000");

        // Format the double value as a string
        String formattedValue = decimalFormat.format(value);

        // Print the formatted value
        System.out.println(formattedValue);
    }
}
```